# Principal $\mathbb S^1$-bundle

Tags: general-topology, principal-bundles

Why if $M$ is a complex surface, $H^2(M;\mathbb Z)$ is classifying $\mathbb S^1$-bundles ? I know $H^2(M;\mathbb Z)$ does classify complex line bundle (just using the exponential sequence for continous complex-valued functions). Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$C-\{0\}$ retracts to $S^1$, thus $H^2(M,Z)$ classifies also $S^1$-bundles if it classifies $C-\{0\}$ bundle.

Comment: I am confused. I don't know a lot about it but for me $H^2(M;Z) \cong H^1(X, \mathcal C(X)^*)$ where $\mathcal C(X)^*$ is the sheaf of continuous, complex valued functions which does not vanishes. This is the cocyle for complex line bundle (with continuous transitions functions). Thus this should classify line bundle instead of $\mathbb C^*$ bundle isn't ? If I'm mistaken, I agree that $S^1$ bundle and $\mathbb C^*$ bundles should be the same !

Comment: To a line bundle is associated a $C^*$-bundle which has the same transition functions.

Comment: I am confused again. For me $C^*$ bundle would be bundle with fiber $C^*$ and line bundle with fiber $C$.

Comment: The transition functions of a $C$-bundle does not vanish, so they define a $C^*$ bundle which is also the associated principal reduction.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations. Sorry I am really slow : so every $C^*$ bundle can be extended into a complex line bundle, and every complex line bundle define a $C^*$ bundle by removing the origin, thus they are equivalent ? Is this what you mean ?

Comment: it is what i mean.

Comment: Great, sorry for asking lot of questions, thanks again for all your explanations !!